# Find index of last occurrence of a substring in a string

Tags: python, string

I want to find the position (or index) of the last occurrence of a certain substring in given input string `str`.

For example, suppose the input string is `str = 'hello'` and the substring is `target = 'l'`, then it should output 3.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 865, accepted):

Use [`.rfind()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind):

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> s.rfind('l')
3
```

Also don't use `str` as variable name or you'll shadow the built-in [`str()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#str).

Answer (score 121):

You can use [`rfind()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rfind#str.rfind) or [`rindex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rfind#str.rindex) 
<sup>Python2 links: [`rfind()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rfind)  [`rindex()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rindex)</sup>

```
>>> s = 'Hello StackOverflow Hi everybody'

>>> print( s.rfind('H') )
20

>>> print( s.rindex('H') )
20

>>> print( s.rfind('other') )
-1

>>> print( s.rindex('other') )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
```

The difference is  when the substring is not found, `rfind()` returns `-1` while `rindex()` raises an exception [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) (Python2 link: [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError)).

If you do not want to check the `rfind()` return code `-1`, you may prefer `rindex()` that will provide an understandable error message. Else you may search for minutes where the unexpected value `-1` is coming from within your code...

---

#### Example: Search of last newline character

```
>>> txt = '''first line
... second line
... third line'''

>>> txt.rfind('\n')
22

>>> txt.rindex('\n')
22
```

Comment: Hi @JacobSchneider. I have added an example according to your comment. I do not understand your issue. Please provide more information: Python version, Content of your string... Cheers

Answer (score 50):

Use the `str.rindex` method.

```
>>> 'hello'.rindex('l')
3
>>> 'hello'.index('l')
2
```

Comment: This will throw an error if the word not found in the string. Using rfind would be better.

Answer (score 13):

Not trying to resurrect an inactive post, but since this hasn't been posted yet...

(This is how I did it before finding this question)

```
s = "hello"
target = "l"
last_pos = len(s) - 1 - s[::-1].index(target)
```

Explanation: When you're searching for the last occurrence, really you're searching for the first occurrence in the reversed string. Knowing this, I did `s[::-1]` (which returns a reversed string), and then indexed the `target` from there. Then I did `len(s) - 1 - the index found` because we want the index in the *unreversed* (i.e. original) string.

Watch out, though! If `target` is more than one character, you probably won't find it in the reversed string. To fix this, use `last_pos = len(s) - 1 - s[::-1].index(target[::-1])`, which searches for a reversed version of `target`.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because, though not too useful for the original question, it was interesting and educational in general. I think much of one's learning of Python is just like this.

Comment: Especially in an interview context where they might not want you to use built-in methods, that's useful

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
s = 'hello plombier pantin'
print (s.find('p'))
6
print (s.index('p'))
6
print (s.rindex('p'))
15
print (s.rfind('p'))
15
```

Answer (score 4):

For this case both `rfind()` and `rindex()` string methods can be used, both will return the highest index in the string where the substring is found like below.

```
test_string = 'hello'
target = 'l'
print(test_string.rfind(target))
print(test_string.rindex(target))
```

But one thing should keep in mind while using `rindex()` method, **rindex()** method raises a ValueError [substring not found] if the target value is not found within the searched string, on the other hand `rfind()` will just return -1.

Answer (score 3):

The [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) library offers tools for finding indices of all *characters* or all *substrings*.

**Given**

```
import more_itertools as mit


s = "hello"
pred = lambda x: x == "l"
```

**Code**

*Characters*

Now there is the [`rlocate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.rlocate) tool available:

```
next(mit.rlocate(s, pred))
# 3
```

A complementary tool is [`locate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.locate):

```
list(mit.locate(s, pred))[-1]
# 3

mit.last(mit.locate(s, pred))
# 3
```

---

*Substrings*

There is also a `window_size` parameter available for locating the leading item of several items:

```
s = "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?"
substring = "chuck"
pred = lambda *args: args == tuple(substring)

next(mit.rlocate(s, pred=pred, window_size=len(substring)))
# 59
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python String rindex() Method**

**Description**
Python string method rindex() returns the last index where the substring str is found, or raises an exception if no such index exists, optionally restricting the search to string[beg:end].

**Syntax** 
Following is the syntax for rindex() method −

```
str.rindex(str, beg=0 end=len(string))
```

**Parameters**
str − This specifies the string to be searched.

beg − This is the starting index, by default its 0

len − This is ending index, by default its equal to the length of the string.

**Return Value**
This method returns last index if found otherwise raises an exception if str is not found.

**Example**
The following example shows the usage of rindex() method.

Live Demo

## !/usr/bin/python

```
str1 = "this is string example....wow!!!";
str2 = "is";

print str1.rindex(str2)
print str1.index(str2)
```

When we run above program, it produces following result −

```
5
2
```

*Ref: [Python String rindex() Method
- Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rindex.htm#:~:text=Python%20string%20method%20rindex(),string%5Bbeg%3Aend%5D.)*

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wanna use [rfind](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) then this will do the trick/

```
def find_last(s, t):
    last_pos = -1
    while True:
        pos = s.find(t, last_pos + 1)
        if pos == -1:
            return last_pos
        else:
            last_pos = pos
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Last Occurrence of a Character in a String without using inbuilt functions
str = input("Enter a string : ")
char = input("Enter a character to serach in string : ")
flag = 0
count = 0
for i in range(len(str)):
    if str[i] == char:
        flag = i
if flag == 0:
    print("Entered character ",char," is not present in string")
else:
    print("Character ",char," last occurred at index : ",flag)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `rindex()` function to get the last occurrence of a character in string

```
s="hellloooloo"
b='l'
print(s.rindex(b))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
str = "Hello, World"
target='l'
print(str.rfind(target) +1)
```

or

```
str = "Hello, World"
flag =0
target='l'
for i,j in enumerate(str[::-1]):
    if target == j:
       flag = 1
       break;
if flag == 1:   
    print(len(str)-i)
```