# How to preserve only the final occurrence of a character in a sentence?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to split the sentence into two columns (Review and Sentiment).

Let us assume that we have a sentence:

Hi... I earn 7 dot 50 per hour i.e $7.50/hr. Positive

Here, "Positive" is the Sentiment and the former is the Review.

i) I cannot use \s as delimiter to split the sentence into two columns(Review,Sentiment)
ii) If I use '.' as delimiter then multiple occurrences of '.' is present in the sentence.

I have written a code to remove the multiple occurrences of '.' and
the code is as below:

```
def clean(sentence):
  clear = re.sub(r"[,|\"|\"|\'|\'|\-|!|?|\/|*|:|\\|\(|\)|;|$]",'', sentence)
  clear1 = re.sub(r'(\W)\1+',' ', clear)
  [' '.join(clear1.split())]
```

which is able to remove "..." after the word "hi" but fails for "i.e" and "$7.50".

My desired result is:

**Review: Hi I earn 7 dot 50 per hour i e 7 50 hr

Sentiment: Positive**

My output is:

Hi I earn 7 dot 50 per hour i.e 7.50 hr.

PS: I am using pandas to load it as a dataframe of two columns

**Edit1:** My sentiment contains either "Positive" or "Negative" in my case.
**Edit2:** I am storing this output as a csv file and I am reading using pandas(read_csv())

Comment: Can you just split with `\.\s*(?=[^.]*$)` (the last dot)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find index of last occurrence of a substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572490/find-index-of-last-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

Comment: Or, `df['col'].str.extract(r'^(.*?)\s*(Positive|Negative)\s*$')`?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572490/find-index-of-last-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-a-string) maybe, but the answer there will help you find the last `.` character, and from there you can trivially get all the characters before it and all after it.

Comment: Why is this marked a possible duplicate when this case is entirely different?

Comment: @SanjeevRam - I don't think it's entirely different, is it? You're trying to work out how to find the last occurrence of the substring ".", that's what that other question is answering.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the last occurrence of dot sign, you can use this regex:

```
\.(?!.*\.)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/OYkupF/2

Answer (score 1):

Find all groups of word characters and use the lists:

```
>>> import re
>>> l = re.findall(r'\w+', s)
>>> ' '.join(l[:-1])
'Hi I earn 7 dot 50 per hour i e 7 50 hr'
>>> l[-1]
'Positive'
```

Answer (score 0):

If sentiment is only 'Positive' or 'Negative'. Then,

```
def clean(sentence):
    tokens = sentence.split()
    return " ".join(tokens[:-1]), tokens[-1]
```

which will give a tuple,

```
('Hi... I earn 7 dot 50 per hour i.e $7.50/hr.', 'Positive')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, as you know that the sentiment will always be "Positive" or "Negative" you can get your 2 columns like this :

```
m = re.match(r"(?P<review>.*)\. (?P<sentiment>Positive|Negative)$", sentence)
m.group('review')
m.group('sentiment')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)?

This will split on space only if it is followed by `Positive` or `Negative`

```
import re

sentence = 'Hi... I earn 7 dot 50 per hour i.e $7.50/hr. Positive'
res = re.split(r'\s+(?=Positive|Negative)', sentence)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['Hi... I earn 7 dot 50 per hour i.e $7.50/hr.', 'Positive']
```