# How do I extract a certain substring using recursion?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a method that takes a substring consisting of two parts:

```
name: idnumber
```

Yes the name and the id are separated by a colon (`:`), for example:

```
A:1313
B:4141
```

The method should return `A` for the first example and `B` for the second but it also should accept special cases, for example:

```
A$%#@$@#!__231:2 
A:::$@$@:::!$@:4
```

The above code should return `A$%#@$@#!__231` for the first line and  `A:::$@$@:::!$@` for the second line.

I tried to do this recursively and here is my code:

```
j=0
def name(input):
  global j
  item = ''
  item = input[j:]
  if ':' in item:
    return name(input[j+1:])
  else:
    return input[:j - 1]
```

This code returns nothing and I'm not sure why it's not working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look fro `split()`

Comment: Split won't work in a special case where the input is `A$@$@:::::$@$!:4`, here I have multiple ":", splitting by ":" results in a faulty output.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for `rpartition()`:

```py
input = ["A:1313",
         "B:4141",
         "A$%#@$@#!__231:2",
         "A:::$@$@:::!$@:4",
        ]

for item in input:
    print(item.rpartition(":")[0])
```

Gives:

```
A
B
A$%#@$@#!__231
A:::$@$@:::!$@
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, 'j' is not neccessory

---

This is works with your request

```
r = 'A:::$@$@:::!$@:4'
pos = r.rfind(':') #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572490
print(r[:pos])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it via split join combination, i.e. as follows:

```
example1 = 'A$%#@$@#!__231:2'
example2 = 'A:::$@$@:::!$@:4'
def getname(x):
    return ':'.join(x.split(':')[:-1])
print(getname(example1)) # A$%#@$@#!__231
print(getname(example2)) # A:::$@$@:::!$@
```

Function that I created gets string, split it at `:`, discards last element (*idnumber* in your case) and then join it together with `:`. Note that it will return empty `str` if there is not `:` inside input.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply ignore values with multiple colons, then use the `split()` method as you normally would:

```
def splitter(id_strings = []):
  return [id if "::" in id else id.split(":")[0] for id in id_strings]
```

You could also convert it to a `lambda` method:

```
splitter = lambda id_strings = []: [id if "::" in id else id.split(":")[0] for id in id_strings]
```

Usage for `splitter()` method:

```
print(splitter(["A:1313", "B:1414", "A$%#@$@#!__231", "A:::$@$@:::!$@"]))
```

Expected output for both methods:

```
["A", "B", "A$%#@$@#!__231", "A:::$@$@:::!$@"]
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex with search

```
import re
samples=["A$%#@$@#!__231:2","A:::$@$@:::!$@:4","A:1313","B:4141"]
res=[ re.search("((.*( by )?.*):(.*))",s).group(2,4) for s in samples]
print(res)
```

and you get `(key, value)` dict

```
[('A$%#@$@#!__231', '2'), ('A:::$@$@:::!$@', '4'), ('A', '1313'), ('B', '4141')]
```

Repl: https://repl.it/@loretoparisi/How-do-I-extract-a-certain-substring-using-recursion