# returning last character placement instead of first with find()

Tags: python, python-3.x, find

I am working on a program for a school project that is supposed to work like a wordsearch. We need to find a word (or words) in a string and print where it is in the string. seems easy enough. Here's an example:

```
yew = "hello"
myString = "alskdfjhelloadskjf"
print(myString.find(yew))
```

This prints `7`, as expected. My professor also wants us to be able to find words that are backward, here is an example of my code that also worked

```
myString = "alskdfjollehadskjf"
print(myString.find(yew[::-1]))
```

This also prints `7`, however, my professor wants the program to print the placement of the first letter in the word, so in this case I want it to print `11`. The only way I found so far to solve this issue is as follows

```
print(myString.find(yew[::-1]) + len(yew) - 1) # prints 11
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this that I am not seeing? or an alternative to `find()` you think would better suit this program? Thanks!

edit: is there a way to write this in a more condensed manner* not necessarily more efficient because as we can see it works fine. sorry for not clarifying

Comment: What is inefficient about this? What is your criteria?

Comment: In other words, your program works, but you want to find an easier way to solve this problem. Am I correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find index of last occurrence of a substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572490/find-index-of-last-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

Comment: Python has so many ways to complete tasks, I was wanted to see if there were any built-in functions that would automatically do this. and @PM77-1 I looked at that but it only is talking about repeating characters, such as the second 'l'

Comment: `print(myString.find(yew[::-1]))` prints `-1` and `print(myString.find(yew[::-1]) + len(yew) - 1) ` prints `3`

Comment: @ChristopherCruttenden then *say that*, be specific about what you are asking. Efficiency implies certain things in the context of programming, so that is a vague way of putting it. is `yew` supposed to be `'olleh'`?  or else I'm not sure I'm following you

Comment: @CONvid19 yes in my code i swapped hello in myString to olleh, I'm fixing it in the question right now

Comment: What are you supposed to do if *no* match is found, or are you allowed to assume a match *will* be found?

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. I figured I would just have to add an if statement to see if `find(yew[::-1]) == -1`. It would be an extra line of code but I don't know what else I'd do because my equation above will always have a different value depending on the string @chepner

Comment: If you know the `yew` won't contain any regular-expression metacharacters, you could use `re.search(yew[::-1], myString).end()`, but I would probably stick with what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think there’s anything wrong with your implementation; in fact, that was the first thing I thought of before I saw your solution. It makes perfect sense that if you want to find the position of the last character in a word, you would find it at `len(word) - 1`. It looks like you did fine!

Comment: I think the OP wants a more efficient way of solving this problem. Maybe he wants a shorter solution.

Comment: @TheMaker **what does inefficient mean**? The OP hasn't clarified

Comment: I think the OP wants a shorter solution. "Is there a more efficient way to do this that I am not seeing? or an alternative to find() you think would better suit this program? Thanks!".