# String cropping based on element occurence in python

Tags: python, string

I wrote these small functions to crop strings before/after the first/last occurence of a symbol in a string:

```
def crop_after_last(string,symbol):
    index=len(string) - string[::-1].index(symbol) - 1
    return string[:index]

def crop_before_last(string,symbol):
    index=len(string) - string[::-1].index(symbol) - 1
    return string[index+1:]

def crop_after_first(string,symbol):
    index=string.index(symbol)
    return string[:index]

def crop_before_first(string,symbol):
    index=string.index(symbol)
    return string[index+1:]
```

I was wandering how this code could be simplified or generalised. Are there built in functions that deal with this problem?

Comment: I'd use [`rfind or rindex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572490/find-index-of-last-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-a-string) instead of reversing, e.g. `s1[:s1.rindex(s2)]`. I don't really see much room to generalize these though, nor do I think there's much software engineering gain to be had in doing so. They're tiny one-liner utilities, time seems better spent elsewhere.

Comment: As an option, you can use `for i, letter in enumerate(string): if letter == symbol: return i