# Parsing PGN string starts with number

Tags: python, chess

Hello everyone I am new to python and try to learn about parsing the string from PGN.

```
'[ECO "B08"]',
 '',
 '1.e4 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4',
 '9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5 12.Nb5 c6 13.Nc7 Rb8 14.f4 Ng4 15.Bxg4 Bd4+',
 '16.Kh1 Bb6 17.f5 Bxc7 18.fxg6 fxg6 19.Bh6 Be5 20.Rad1 Rxd1 21.Rxd1 Bd6 22.Rf1  1-0',
 '',
 '[Event "Telechess ol1 7778"]',
```

The result that I want is just to put the move part into a list

```
1.e4 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4,9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5 12.Nb5 c6 13.Nc7 Rb8 14.f4 Ng4 15.Bxg4 Bd4+ 16.Kh1 Bb6 17.f5 Bxc7 18.fxg6 fxg6 19.Bh6 Be5 20.Rad1 Rxd1 21.Rxd1 Bd6 22.Rf1
```

The approach that I take is by reading the PGN and split by `'\n'`. The output contains a list as the first block of code.
I want to detect by every list that started with a number (one digit or two-digit before the dot '.') should append into a new list.

rough code should be like

```
listmove = []
for i in pgn:
if i.startswith(1digitnumber or twodigitnumber before dot):
listmove.append[i]
```

Is it possible? Guidance will help a lot and will be appreciated.

Comment: Incase you just want to parse the pgn then the [python-chess](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module is worth checking out but if you are doing this to practice python string formatting and stuff then the answer provided by others are certainly some of the best approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible using regular expressions. The regex you need is `^\d+\.` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VX5yo2/1)

Explanation:

- `^`: Start of line / start of string
- `\d+`: One or more digit characters
- `\.`: One period

In python, you'd do:

```
import re


lines = ['[ECO "B08"]',
 '',
 '1.e4 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4',
 '9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5 12.Nb5 c6 13.Nc7 Rb8 14.f4 Ng4 15.Bxg4 Bd4+',
 '16.Kh1 Bb6 17.f5 Bxc7 18.fxg6 fxg6 19.Bh6 Be5 20.Rad1 Rxd1 21.Rxd1 Bd6 22.Rf1  1-0',
 '',
 '[Event "Telechess ol1 7778"]']

regex = r"^\d+\."

movelines = []

for line in lines:
    if re.search(regex, line):
        # This line starts with digits and a period
        movelines.append(line)

print(movelines)
```

prints:

```
[
 '1.e4 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4', 
 '9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5 12.Nb5 c6 13.Nc7 Rb8 14.f4 Ng4 15.Bxg4 Bd4+', 
 '16.Kh1 Bb6 17.f5 Bxc7 18.fxg6 fxg6 19.Bh6 Be5 20.Rad1 Rxd1 21.Rxd1 Bd6 22.Rf1  1-0'
]
```

---

You could also remove the `^` from your regex and use `re.split()` to get the different moves. You can use the fact that `re.match()` searches from the beginning of the line, so use that instead of `re.search()`:

```
split_regex = r"\d+\."

all_moves = []

for line in lines:
    if re.match(split_regex, line):
        moves = re.split(split_regex, line)
        all_moves.extend(moves)

print(all_moves)
```

This prints

```
[
'', 'e4 d6 ', 'd4 Nf6 ', 'Nc3 g6 ', 'Nf3 Bg7 ', 'Be2 Nbd7 ', 'O-O O-O ', 'e5 dxe5 ', 'dxe5 Ng4', 
'', 'e6 Nde5 ', 'Qxd8 Rxd8 ', 'Nxe5 Nxe5 ', 'Nb5 c6 ', 'Nc7 Rb8 ', 'f4 Ng4 ', 'Bxg4 Bd4+',
'', 'Kh1 Bb6 ', 'f5 Bxc7 ', 'fxg6 fxg6 ', 'Bh6 Be5 ', 'Rad1 Rxd1 ', 'Rxd1 Bd6 ', 'Rf1  1-0'
]
```

Notice the extra empty strings at the start of each line. This happens because of the way `re.split()` works, so you can simply ignore the first entry in each line with `all_moves.extend(moves[1:])` to give

```
[
  'e4 d6 ', 'd4 Nf6 ', 'Nc3 g6 ', 'Nf3 Bg7 ', 'Be2 Nbd7 ', 'O-O O-O ', 'e5 dxe5 ', 'dxe5 Ng4', 
  'e6 Nde5 ', 'Qxd8 Rxd8 ', 'Nxe5 Nxe5 ', 'Nb5 c6 ', 'Nc7 Rb8 ', 'f4 Ng4 ', 'Bxg4 Bd4+', 
  'Kh1 Bb6 ', 'f5 Bxc7 ', 'fxg6 fxg6 ', 'Bh6 Be5 ', 'Rad1 Rxd1 ', 'Rxd1 Bd6 ', 'Rf1  1-0'
]
```

The win marker `1-0` is included in this because it's not separated by a move number, but it should be fairly trivial to remove that because it can only be one of three possibilities:

- `1-0` (White wins),
- `0-1` (Black wins)
- `1/2-1/2` (draw)

Comment: thank you so much, I have an enlightenment now. Really curious on the first part with match, I did as you wrote but by assigning ```moveline=" "``` as empty string. I have all the move parts. But now I want to apply to a bigger file. The idea of win marker as a split just popped up in my head. how to achieve that by the way ? I tried the same with regex2 ```r"^\d+\-\d+"``` and do re.split(regex2, moveline). I ended up with empty string

Comment: @Trojan666 Not sure I understand your question. The `^` makes the regex look for whatever comes next _at the start of the line / string_, but the win marker isn't at the start of the line.

Comment: Also, `\d+-\d+` wouldn't work all the time because it would have false positives e.g. `3-1`, or false negatives e.g. `1/2-1/2`. It's better to use `r"\b(?:0|1(?:/2)?)\-(?:0|1(?:/2)?)\b"` (see demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/9eA4om/1))

Comment: no wonder why it is not working because we have draw as well. here what i mean ```move = ""
for line in chess:
    if re.match(regex, line):
        # This line starts with digits and a period
        move = move+line
        
print(move)``` Now I have ```move``` contains all string of move and score. Now i want to split by score then, ```regex2 = r"\b(?:0|1(?:/2)?)\-(?:0|1(?:/2)?)\b"

move_new=[]

for line in move:
    if re.match(regex2, line):
        moves = re.split(regex2, line)
        move_new.extend(moves)

print(move_new)```

it return empty list

Comment: `for line in move` iterates over _each character in the string_ `move`, so `regex2` will never match `line`. The score is usually in the end after a space, isn't it? It's probably easier to remove everything after the last space. To do this, you'd [find the last occurrence of a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572490/find-index-of-last-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-a-string) and then [slice `move` up to the last index you just found](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) @Trojan666

Comment: This will be applied in bigger data, so there will be multiple moves. Let say I save the object move like above. How about iterate and put everything that starts with '1.' until it finds another '1.' put the first string until the last occurrence into a list? Sorry, it is a little bit overwhelming.

Comment: I think you should give it a shot and ask a new question with more details and examples. It's hard to understand what you need to do through a comment. Once you've posted the question, feel free to shoot me the link and I can try to answer it. @Trojan666

Comment: I made it with the guidance of yours. I found one difficulty to separate the move from black and white. I will post it in a new question tho.

Comment: What's the difficulty? Simply splitting by space should do that, no?

Answer (score 0):

The shortest intelligible line you might be interested in should be at least 4 characters (move number, move notation). So you can freely check those first characters for initial validity even up to moves of index 100 or more.

At some stage you might come across lines that start with a Black move, but they still start with a number I believe. ('15. ... Bd4+')

Since an earlier version caused a little confusion, this one splits out the first character test from those subsequent more explicitly:

```py
def good_moves_start(pgnline):
    if len(pgnline) < 4:
        return False
    if pgnline[0] not in '123456789': # first char test
        return False
    for ch in pgnline[1:4]:
        if ch == '.':
            return True               # dot completes move #
        elif not ch.isdecimal():
            return False              # disqual characater
    return False                      # no dot in first 4 chars
```

This only identifies candidate move data of course; there is plenty more validation possible as the moves are read in. It would be interesting to consider how to allow for puzzle boards and chess variants - pieces, board, moves, # of players.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi not quite; I didn't want to allow leading zero for first test, and subsequently '.' is permitted.